# Does there exist a divergent sequence such that $|x_{t+2}-x_{t+1}|<|x_{t+1}-x_t|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

A  **sequence** of real numbers is a function whose domain is an infinite set of natural or integer numbers, and its "path" is a subset of real numbers. The notation $x_t$ is used to describe the values of the sequences, $f (t) = x_t$.
$$f (t) = x_t: A\subseteq \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

**The OA sequence:**

If the distance between two consecutive terms decreases, the sequence is called **OA,** it is to say:
$$|x_{t+2}-x_{t+1}|<|x_{t+1}-x_{t}|  $$ For any t.

**Limit of a sequence:**

We know that a sequence $x_t$ **converge** to $L$, if and only if: $$\lim_{t\to \infty} x_t=L$$

**My question is: Does it exist a OA sequence that diverges?**

Comment: Yes, take for example $\,x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\,$. More generally, take any divergent series, then you can "interpolate" additional terms between the original ones as to make the consecutive differences obey the OA inequality.

Comment: Similar example: $x_n = \log n$.